Custom logout, error "Unable to logout with CSRF token validation"
namespace App\Controller\SecurityController;

use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class SecurityController
{
    #[Route(path: '/logout', name: 'logout')]
    public function someAction(Security $security): Response
    {
        $response = $security->logout();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');  
    }
}

Twig
<a href="{{ path('logout', {'token' : csrf_token('logout')}) }}">

Security
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                check_path: login
                login_path: login
                enable_csrf: true
                default_target_path: /admin


            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%' # required
                lifetime: 2592000 # 1 month in seconds

I get it from documentation Symfony 6.4 but faced with error

Unable to logout with CSRF token validation.

What wrong? I don`t want disable CSRF protection.

Please share your security firewalls configuration and your loginfrom configuration.

Hello @Bademeister added

You are calling csrf_token(‘logout’) with the csrf_token_id logout. But I can not see where you define the csrf_token_id that is used to create the CsrfToken. In this case, the CsrfTokenManager generates a new CsrfToken. In my opinion, this is where the error occurs. If you do not have any special requirements for CsrfToken, you should let Symfony handle the logout handling.
